# Hiding elements in a GridView (used as a ListView's view) completely?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, converters, visibility

I have a `ListView` and a button. Now, when I press the button I want to display only the elements that meet the required criteria. I'm using a converter on the visibility of the items, but if I return `Visibility.Hidden` the items are merely invisible, yet they still take up space. A better alternative is to use `Visibility.Collapsed` which shrinks the items and hides them, but they still take up a bit of space. I need them gone from the `ListView` completely.

Here's the XAML code (I know it's not very clean, but since I have a wide monitor it's easier to have less rows than columns):

```
        <ListView x:Name="lvTereni1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="120" Margin="5" OpacityMask="#CA000000" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SveHale.Hala1}" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="lvTereni1_Click" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Glavna sala" Width="110">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Height="40" Width="80" CornerRadius="15">
                                    <Border.Visibility>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ShowHideConverter}">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding Path="BZauzet" />
                                                <Binding Path="Stanje" />
                                                <Binding ElementName="btnSwap" Path="Text"></Binding>
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Border.Visibility>
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DragAndDropCoverter}">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding ElementName="lvTimovi" Path="SelectedItem" />
                                                <Binding Path="Stanje"/>
                                                <Binding Path="DozvoljeniSportovi" />
                                                <Binding Path="BZauzet" />
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Sifra}">
                                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DragAndDropTextCoverter}">
                                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                    <Binding Path="Stanje"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="BZauzet" />
                                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The `ShowHideConverter` is the interesting converter here (I'm aware that I shouldn't bind the converter to something as relative as the text of a button, but this isn't that big of a project, and the button's text block will always have two states, so...):

```
class ShowHideConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool zauzet = (bool)value[0];
        Teren._Stanje stanje = (Teren._Stanje)value[1];
        string ispis = (string)value[2];
        if (ispis.Equals("Prikaži sve"))
            if (zauzet || stanje == Teren._Stanje.Zatvoren)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your collection (`SveHale.Hala1`) in [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx), and based on button state use [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter.aspx) property. For example, if your button state is bind to property `FilterData` and `Hala1Wrapper` wrapper around your `SveHale.Hala1` collection:

```
public bool FilterData 
{
    set 
    {
        if (value) 
            Hala1Wrapper.Filter = itm => zauzet || ((Teren._Stanje)itm) == Teren._Stanje.Zatvoren;
        else 
            Hala1Wrapper.Filter = null;
    }
}
```

In XAML you must bind `ListView` `ItemsSource` to `CollectionView` wrapper.

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SveHale.Hala1Wrapper}">
```

Comment: Thank you, this works almost completely. I do have one problem and I know a "dirty" way to solve it, but I was wondering if there was something more clean.

Namely, I have a list of soccer fields and a list of teams. When I click the button (FilterData), the list of fields should only show the available ones and it does. However, if I drag a team on a field (in order to occupy it), the field is no longer available (it turns gray, (background is binded to a converter which checks), but I also want it gone from the list.

I could call the filter again, but can I notify it somehow instead?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to call [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh.aspx) method